# Seria possível fazer um projeto em html, css, js, e rodar em um nativo como o android?

Tags: javascript, html, android

Gostaria de saber se é possível criar um projeto em html, css e js, e rodar em um nativo. Se possível, qual plataforma usar?(obs. Projeto simples, custos simples:) ).

Comment: Cara se eu construir em html css e js, ja tira o sentido de nativo, sim é possível criar baseado nessas três ferramentas, porem não será um código nativo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[Progressive Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/)*. Características:

- **Confiabilidade**: Quando lançado a partir da home screen do usuário, *service workers* permitem que um aplicativo da Web Progressivo (ou PWA) seja carregado instantaneamente, independentemente do estado da rede.
- **Rapidez**: Os recursos do aplicativo web são armazenados localmente após a primeira carga. PWAs carregam instantaneamente.
- **Comportamento**: PWAs são instaláveis, ​​e podem ser apresentados como ícones da *home screen* sem a necessidade de instalação a partir da AppStore. Eles também tem permissão de abrir em tela cheia e enviar notificações Push.

Answer (score 2):

Sim, existem o que chamamos de aplicativos híbridos. Eles podem ser criados utilizando frameworks como o [React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/), o [Ionic](https://ionicframework.com/) ou o [NativeScript](https://www.nativescript.org/). Alguns como já disseram não fazem muito mais do que criar um WebView e colocar o seu código por cima utilizando as vantagens do Apache Cordova e do PhoneGap para comunicação com as API's do telefone.

Outros, no entanto, tem uma extensa capacidade de "converter" código front-end em código nativo. Fazendo uma espécie de de-para que melhora muito a performance e a usabilidade do aplicativo, mas em contrapartida possuem bem menos recursos do que seus concorrentes "não-tão-nativos"